# fee economics around remark

Tags: extrinsic, weight, block, fee, substrate-block-time

From looking at [the source code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4b48e8ec7dffcb599248040f4da5be3de3c09318/frame/system/src/weights.rs#L101), it looks like `system` pallet's `remark` extrinsic has null weight.

Even though remarks don't add anything in terms of block execution, one could argue it's still having an influence on block size and therefore having an effect on how fast nodes are able to sync the chain.

How are `remark`s accounted for? What is preventing some troll from flooding the blocks with meaningless remarks without paying proportionally for that priviledge?

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every extrinsic has an `ExtrinsicBaseWeight` which is defined in FRAME System.

So even if a benchmark for a particular extrinsic says 0, there will still be the `ExtrinsicBaseWeight` included on top of it. This is also true for any non-zero weight. The final weight of the extrinsic will be `benchmark_weight + extrinsic_base_weight`.

In fact, we measure the `ExtrinsicBaseWeight` using the `remark` function, so this weight is completely appropriate for the call.

Beyond this base fee, all extrinsics have a `TransactionByteFee` which is set in the Transaction Payment Pallet. This will increase the fees charged to the user based on how many bytes they use in their encoded extrinsic.

So the longer your `remark` message, the larger the fee you will pay.

These two things combined ensure that appropriate fees are paid for `remark` extrinsics.